# How do I kill a process with a specific PID using VB.NET?`

Tags: vb.net, process

I want to kill a process with a specified process id, not name:

```
Dim aProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
aProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
aProcess.Kill()
```

What is the best way to do that using VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the PID, you should do:

```
Dim aProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
aProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(PID)
aProcess.Kill()
```